# add indent when the file has spaces (upload files)

Tags: php, image

I am using a system to upload images, files... with PHP, and I'm having trouble putting '-' in files that have spaces... how can I put so that all the images I upload and have spaces, put a indent? ( - )

my code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir .  date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

    if($target_file = null) {
        echo"nada";
    }
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {

        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using str_replace would be the easiest way in my opinion.

```
$target_file = $target_dir . date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'. str_replace(' ','-',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: This did not work, where rename the file is here  "$target_file = $target_dir .  date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . '_'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];"

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect where you want it done.